# Firebase's "Users in last 30 minutes" doesn't count session starts

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I've added firebase to my application. When I go to Firebase, Analytics, Dashboard, I can see that the **Users in last 30 minutes** panel shows new installations. But when I reopen an already installed application, it doesn't count them.

What can be wrong?